# Retrieve specific index in Mongo array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have many entities with a big array for each on these entities in DB. I want to retrieve the first and the last element of the array (there is too much data if I get all the arrays). How can I do it ?
I tried this:

```
db.my_collection.findOne({my_query:'is_awesome'}, {'big_array.0':1})
```

but it doesn't work...
Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation instead of `findOne`, performing a `$match`.

In Mongodb 3.2, there is `$slice` in aggregation, so you can `$slice` the item at position 1 and -1 :

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([{
    $match: { my_query: 'is_awesome' }
}, {
    $project: {
        my_query: 1,
        firstElement: { $slice: ["$big_array", 1] },
        lastElement: { $slice: ["$big_array", -1] }
    }
}])
```

In Mongodb < 3.2, `$slice` cant be used in aggregation, so you can use an `$unwind` and `$group`, the following is working in Mongodb 3.0 :

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([{
    $match: { my_query: 'is_awesome' }
}, {
    $unwind: "$big_array"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        my_query: { $first: "$my_query" },
        firstElement: { $first: "$big_array" },
        lastElement: { $last: "$big_array" }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank's ! Is it only available for MongoDB version 3.1 at least ?

Comment: ```mongo --version``` give me 3.0.8. Then I have the following error with your trick :
```assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$slice'",
        "code" : 15999,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$slice'",
        "code" : 15999,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed```
Did I miss something ?

Comment: My bad, `$slice` in aggregation is only for 3.2+, I've updated my post with a solution working in 3.0

Comment: It works ! It's not very fast but solve perfectly my problem. Thank's a lot !